# calling object properties in N levels javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm using mongodb and ajax calls to retrieve data. When it turns to javascript object, the properties that I use to generate html sometimes don't exist.
Look at this call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'api/v1/mention/'+id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {login : "demo"},
        success: function(mention) {
            display_mention_text(mention.texto);
        }
    });
```

In this case i'm calling mention.texto, but could be mention.picture or any properties. Sometimes it is undefined and crashes the app.

This method calls a property from a object and if its undefined , return an empty string.
Some examples for calling this method(the first one is an object, the other are properties):

```
get_property(mention,"text")
get_property(mention,"user","name")
get_property(mention,"picture")
```

The method is defined as follows:

```
function get_property(obj){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
     obj = args.shift();
    if (checkNested(obj,args)) {
       //what should I do here?
    } else{
                   //the property is undefined and returns ""
        "";
    };
}


    //check if a object has N levels of propertys
function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
      obj = args.shift();

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}
```

In the first method get_property, if the property do exist, how do I call that??
I would have the object and his propertys as an array like:
object

```
params = ["user","name"]
```

but I can't call like following:

```
object.["user","name"]
```

Comment: Replace the `if` statement in the `get_property` function with the `for` loop from the `checkNested` function. Then instead of returning `true` or `false`, return the value found or `""`.

Comment: but the function checkNested is return true or false, not the value.

Comment: I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13345966/1689607) that does what I explained. But again, you *replace* the entire `if` statement, and put in its place the `for` statement from the other function. Then *change* the return values so you're no longer returning `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `if` statement in the `get_property` function with the `for` loop from the `checkNested` function. Then instead of returning `true` or `false`, return the value found or `""`.

```
function get_property(obj){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        obj = args.shift();

     // Here's your 'for' loop. The 'if' statement is gone.
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
          return "";   // I changed the value of this 'return' statement
        }
        obj = obj[args[i]];
    }
    return obj;  // I change the value of this 'return' statement
}
```

Again, all I did was copy paste your own code from one function to the other, and change the values of the `return` statements.

Comment: this code is very cool, I was so focused on the new method that forgot about the other

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by this way (no need of `checkNested` function):

```
//Parameters    {obj, prop1, prop2, ... propN}
function get_property(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
       obj = args.shift(),
       prop = args.shift();

    if( obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ){
        if( args.length > 0 ){
           //Calling 'get_property' with  {obj[prop1], prop2, ... propN} , and so on
           return get_property.apply(get_property, [obj[prop]].concat(args));
        }else{
           return obj[prop];
        }
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}​
```

*Usage:*

```
var o = {
    "a" : {
        "b" : 5
    }
};

console.log( get_property(o,"c") );        //  ""
console.log( get_property(o,"a","b") );    //  5
console.log( get_property(o,"a") );        //  {"b":5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for a simple recursive function.

```
function get_property(obj, prop) {
    if (obj[prop]) {
        return obj[prop];
    }
    else {
        var end;
        for (var p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                end = get_property(obj[p], prop);
            }
        }
        if (!end) {
            // If we're there, it means there's no property in any nested level
            return;
        }
        else {
            return end;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: looks like I misinterpreted your question. See @Engineer's answer instead. Keeping this answer in case someone looks like for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. If you know the tree of your object, just call:

```
obj['user']['name'];
```

If you're expecting undefined properties (and really, that means there's something else wrong):

```
var prop;
try {
    prop = obj.user.name;
}
catch (e) {
    prop = null;
}
```

Comment: Actually in this case he'd better use `obj.user.name` for readability's sake.

Comment: @ThiefMaster sure, whatever suits him best.

Comment: I know the three of the object, but the property name of object user could be undefined. If that's the case obj['user']['name'] would raise an exception.

Comment: @RodrigoDias then I prefer the `try/catch` expression. It's made especially to handle this: exceptions.

Comment: I've read in other post that raising exceptions with that problem could mess things up. It is not right to raise exceptions when you don't need to .