# "Cannot read property of '<propName>' of undefined" even though it's defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined-behavior

I came across a really strange bug with Javascript on NodeJS.

I have a huge data.json file (24MB). I read it via

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data.json", 'utf8'));
```

However, at some point during the script execution, I try to access, for example,

```
data['someProp']['prop1']
```

and it raises a type error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop1' of undefined

It is really strange because `data`, `data['someProp']`, `data['someProp']['prop1']` are all defined.

If I do

```
console.log(data['someProp']['prop1']);
```

it displays the value of `data['someProp']['prop1']` on the screen **correctly** and raises a type error immediately.

What might cause this strange behaviour? Any guess or tip to fix such a problem?

---

Update:

Let me be a bit clearer. I find it strange because if I put

```
console.log(data['someProp']['prop1']);
```

in the line just above where it raised the error, it **correctly** prints out the value and immediately raises an error.

Let's say `data['someProp']['prop1'] = "someProp value"`.

Then this is the error log.

```
someProp value

console.log(data['someProp']['prop1']);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop1' of undefined
```

So if I do

```
console.log(data['someProp'])
```

Then this is the log I get:

```
{
  ...
  "someProp": {
    "prop1": "someProp value"
  },
  ...
}
undefined
```

This is the part I'm confused. When I console.log it, it prints out the contents of `data['someProp']` followed immediately by `undefined`. What can cause this?

Another strange thing is

```
console.log(typeof data['someProp']);
```

The result is:

```
object
undefined
```

How can `data['someProp']` be object as well as `undefined`?

Comment: *"...at some point during the script execution..."* Well that would seem to be the key, wouldn't it. If it's telling you that it's `undefined`, then that means it's `undefined`. Either you're running the code before it's defined, or you're accessing properties incorrectly. Either way, the issue can't be known from what you've provided.

Comment: take a look at this question, it has a function to call properties on n levels and returns empty string if it is null. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345449/calling-object-properties-in-n-levels-javascript

Comment: @user1689607 Could you take a look at my updated question? I'm confused because console.log displays the value correctly and immediately complains that it's undefined. I'm wondering if this is caused by some corrupted text encoding in data.json file. But that's just my wild guess.

Comment: Could you post some of your code verbatim?

Comment: The return value of `console.log` is `undefined`. That's not part of what's being logged. If you do `console.log("foo")`, you'll get `"foo" undefined`. Regarding your issue, we need a working example to see what's going on. Seems like there may be some async code in play

Comment: Perhaps your code is actually being run *twice* -- once successfully, and then again unsuccessfully. Try adding multiple `console.log` statements. If my guess is correct, they should all succeed and then the first one will finally report an error (at the beginning of the second pass).

Comment: Second, less-likely guess: has someone wrapped your `console.log` function with extra functionality?

Comment: @user1689607 Hey, as you guessed, the code involves some async code. And while I was debugging just now, I realized that when I call done() callback, I didn't return. I fixed those async issues and the problem is resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: feel free to either delete the question or answer it yourself and accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll answer my own question and close this question.

As user1689607 guessed, there was a bug with my async code. For example, my code looked like:

```
function test(done) {
  ...
  if (err) {
    done();
  }
  ...
  if (data['someProp']['prop1']) {
    ...
    done();
  }
}
```

Since the first done() was called without return, I think it comes back at the end of the callback execution and goes through the rest of the code, which it shouldn't. During that time, there has been some changes to data and that's what caused the error.

So `return done();` fixed the problem.

Thanks @user1689607.